# CRM 2011 Case Entity Event Handler not executing each time

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I have my javascript file `case_Javascript.js` and it have a function `poupulate javascript`.

I have call this function on `OnLoad` of case entity.

I have used an alert("script runing") in the start of the js file. Only first time the `alert()` is shown. And its not runing then. I have to reset iis and publish each time to run this and it wont run again. I am stuck. Any Solution to get around?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your JS file?

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache, before giving it an IIS reset and publishing every time? It could be a browser issue, I have faced it a couple of times.

Comment: I do not know what was the problem...but it is now runing fine. I could not find the reason why it was not firing but now it is up and runing by itself.
Thanks

Comment: @glosrob I have nothing in js file. just debugger and alert().

Comment: @CRMJunkie Yes i tried couple of times clearing the cache but it would not fire.

Comment: @SAQIBKHAN Well good to know it's working for you! (:

Answer (score 0):

This could be the settings of your IE.

IE >Tools > Internet Options > General Tab > Browsing History Settings > 
Check for newer version of stored pages > Option "Never" radio button is checked or not

Set this to "Automatically".

Comment: It is set to "Automatically" by Default.